# Trying to add Crashlytics in Xamarin forms iOS app

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

we are trying to integrate Crashlytics in Xamarin.Forms iOS, we tried using the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics, But we don't have any type of documentation related to this integrated

while we integrate and add references then we are getting this error

```
/Users/apple/.nuget/packages/xamarin.firebase.ios.crashlytics/3.10.9/build/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics.targets(3,3): Error MSB3073: The command "'/Users/apple/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/Fbrc-1.7.13/upload-symbols' -gsp '/Users/apple/Desktop/Xamarin-Forms/Sympl/Latest/sympl-mobile-app/App.iOS/GoogleService-Info.plist' -p ios 'bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.4-12.0/App.iOS.app.dSYM'" exited with code 132. (MSB3073)
```

For using that Package Fabric is mandatory ? with out fabric we were not able to use just firebase Crashlytics ?

Comment: If I remember correctly Crashlytics in Firebase still depends on Fabric yes. It's a first step, but it's not standalone yet, just a bridge to get your crash datas from Fabric, inside your Firebase back-end. 
So to answer your question, you should follow the Fabric documentation to setup your project (you will need XCode).
That being said, to my experience, Fabric integration for Xamarin apps is bad, at best. If you have the option, consider user Microsoft's App Center crash SDK, which is a lot easier to integrate

Comment: Check this thread to see if it helps:[how-to-setup-crashlytics-in-xamarin-android-and-ios](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84635/could-you-provide-the-details-of-how-to-setup-crashlytics-in-xamarin-android-and-ios).